# How do I access Drupal's admin panel?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9, platform.sh

This might be a weird question, but I'm with an agency that just took over a website that was built on platform.sh and Drupal 9. The previous agency is having zero communications with the client, and the client knows nothing of how Drupal works - and neither do I or my team.

We have access to their platform.sh panel, but we have zero clue how to login to the Drupal CMS admin to make simple changes to the site. Is there a generic URL parameter we can append to the environment URL to get to the admin login? Orrr....

Sorry this is vague, I'm not even sure how to ask what we need. But, I'm fairly certain a simple page update or coupon generation isn't only done through code and deployments just based on my experience with Magento, SFCC, and Shopify.

We have downloaded the site code through platform.sh and have tried adding `login` and `admin` to the end of the environment URL, but that didn't take us to a login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the drush command `drush user:login` to get a one-time login URL and used that to create users and get the Admin URL we needed